# Build SQL query from multiple arrays - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array that looks like this..

```
Array
(
    [fm] => Array
        (
            [133.74] => Array
                (
                    [base] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2015-09-29
                            [1] => 2015-09-30
                        )

                )

            [202.59] => Array
                (
                    [base] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2015-10-01
                        )

                )

        )

    [fmtax] => Array
        (
            [13.51] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-09-29
                    [1] => 2015-09-30
                )

            [20.46] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-10-01
                )

        )

)
```

and I need to build a SQL statement to insert the relevant values.  I'm thinking it will need to be a unique query for each array  item.

So I'll end up needing something like

```
$sql = "insert into mytable ('price', 'tax', 'date')
         values ('133.74', '13.51', '2015-09-29')";
```

What I've got so far is this...

```
foreach ($sale['fm'] as $key => $value) {
    $i=0;
    $g=count($value['base']);
    while($i < $g) {
        echo($sale['fm'][$key]['base'][$i]."<br />");
        $i++;
    }
}
```

which does well for the "fm" key - but I'm getting hung up on how to grab the value from the second **associated** "fmtax" array key.  I was thinking using something like current/next as it iterates through...but am kinda scratching my head on it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `fm` and `fmtax` both have same number of elements and the order of related elements (price and tax) from `fm` and `fmtax` are same. What you can do is - store the taxes from `fmtax` with simple keys in this way :

```
$taxes = array();
$c = 0;
foreach ($sale['fmtax'] as $key => $value) {
    $taxes[$c] = $key;
    $c++;
}
```

Then you can access this new `$taxes` array from your own code block in this way :

```
$c = 0;  
foreach ($sale['fm'] as $key => $value) {
    //Here you have the related tax
    $tax = $taxes[$c];

    $i=0;
    $g=count($value['base']);
    while($i < $g) {
        echo($sale['fm'][$key]['base'][$i]."<br />");
        $i++;
    }

    $c++;
}
```